# How to make some improvements to my Excel macro code?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to excel macros. Started learning it a week ago. I have a requirement for which I copied codes from few programs using google. But now I am getting error. Not sure how to fix it.

All I am trying to do is:

1. Copy item 1 (Cell: A1) from sheet2 'partslist' to sheet1 'form' to cell G2
2. Save only sheet1 'form' as a separate file in specific folder (I can mention the path)

   If possible please let me know if I can search a folder structure using the part number and if that folder exist then save it under that folder with a name XXX.part number.xls. Else save it under default path I specify using name XXX.part number.xls
3. Jump to next part number in sheet2 'partslist' and continue step 1 and 2 till all part numbers are finished.

---

```
Sub test code ()
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim FName As String
    Dim FPath As String

    Set form = Sheets("form")
    Set partslist = Sheets("partslist")

    lastRow = partslist.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        If partslist.Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then
           form.Range("G11").Value = partslist.Range("A" & i).Value

        End If

        Set FPath = "C:\"
        Set FName = Sheets("partslist").Range("A" & i).Text

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SIR").SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error and on which line is it showing to be in error?  One glaring mistake is that you cannot have a two work name as a SUB.

Comment: There is a [`Worksheet.SaveAs` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) which is very similar to `Workbook.SaveAs` method. You can use this method e.g., `form.SaveAs...` to save the specific sheet to a new file.

Comment: Compiler error: object required

Comment: On which line?  Which line is highlighted when you debug?

Comment: This code is not complete. It would be helpful if someone can give me a complete code based on the code I have written. It will help me to compare and learn my mistakes.

Comment: I see that very first line is highlighted sub testcode()

Comment: It's probably on this line: `Set FPath = "C:\"` as you're using `Set` but you don't need to because it's a string, use: `FPath = "C:\"`. The same with your `FName` variable.

Comment: You do know you're setting your filepath as `C:\\\`` [er, that ` at the end shouldn't be there, don't know how to format it out in comments] and `Fname`, yes? Either remove the slash from the `Set FPath`, or the `\` from the `SaveAs`.  Also, with `String` you don't need `Set`.

Comment: @Andy This site is not a code for me site.  We are here to help overcome a specific problem not, rewrite your whole code and expand it to do what it does not currently do.

Comment: Use `Application.FileDialog` to browse for the folder in which you want to save the file. Also for worksheet saving refer to link [Worksheet Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837784.aspx)

Comment: I corrected the path but when I click run it highlights Fpath and gives object required error

Comment: Did you remove the `Set` as @Jordan stated?

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well if I remove set which is before filepath it gives  'Runtime error 9: subscript out of range

Comment: You do not need `Set` on either those two lines, you do not set a string.  Check your spelling of the worksheet, It is not finding the worksheet in the active workbook.

Comment: I need more practice :( This is more difficult than I thought :(

Answer (score 0):

A few errors that may be fixed are:

1. Declare all your variables with the suitable type.
   For instance,

   ```
   Set form = Sheets("form")
   ```

   should be preceded (and likewise for `partslist`) with

   ```
   Dim form as Worksheet
   ```
2. Do not use `Set` with strings.

Comment: I modified code slightly and got it to work for one part but when I have list of parts and tried to loop the macro it failed again :( Can anyone help fixing this code  plz...

Comment: @Andy - Whenever you get an error, the best way to get help is: 1) Post a minimalistic, fully standalone code that gives the error, with an image of the worksheet if needed. This requires work on your side (debugging) to isolate the set of lines/case which when combied produces the error. Sometimes one can be somewhat flexible on this, but you provided nothing. 2) Indicate the line producing the error. 3) Post the error returned, *Verbatim*. Otherwise, people have to guess too much... When helping becomes impossible, people simply don't try it.